# Using 'now' in sqlite date arithmetic

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a sqlite table with a date field in YYYYMMDD format as an integer (so 20131204 = Dec 4, 2013) and the field name is cycleStarted.

I am trying to count the number of days from dateStarted to today (in this case where cycleStared = 10).

I'm having a bit of a problem - here's my sql - which needless to say - doesn't work;

```
SELECT  julianday(substr('now', 1, 4) || '-' ||
substr('now', 5, 2) || '-' ||
substr('now', 7, 2)) -
julianday(substr(cyclestarted, 1, 4) || '-' ||
substr(cyclestarted, 5, 2) || '-' ||
substr(cyclestarted, 7, 2))
FROM cycles WHERE cycleid = 10
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: The right direction is to not rely on yyyymmdd producing useful integers with which you can do math.  The end of the month and end of the year will mess you up.

Comment: Read this.  http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
    SELECT CAST(JULIANDAY('NOW') - JULIANDAY(SUBSTR(cyclestarted, 1, 4) || '-' || SUBSTR(cyclestarted, 5, 2) || '-' || SUBSTR(cyclestarted, 7, 2)) AS INT)
      FROM cycles
      WHERE cycleid = 10
```

Answer (score 3):

You're taking substrings of the *string literal* `'now'`, not of the current date.  If you want the current Julian date, you can simply write `julianday('now')`.